# Why and where is Ruby writing to disk when using Open()

Tags: ruby, file-io, memory-leaks

I have a PHP script that serves a string on my localhost, like so:

> {"mx":"704","my":"261","top":"-1000px","left":"-1157px","width":"4582","height":"3522","articleHeader":"false","wwidth":"1366","wheight":"665","time":1370692442}

I'm reading that url with ruby, utilizing either **open-uri's** or **net-http**. Like so, for example:

```
r = Net::HTTP.get( URI.parse( 'http://localhost/_inc/server.php') )
```

or

```
data = open('http://localhost/_inc/server.php')
```

I noticed (using *'watch df'*) that my disk usage (the root filesystems) increases with every cycle by the size of that string under the url. Upon aborting the script, the space isn't cleared back to initial state (the difference is far greater then whatever is being written to /tmp) I don't need to keep that string in memory, I'd like it do be discarded.

I assume that *open/read* creates a new buffer(?) but why is it written to my hdd? Where can I find those files and how to actually discard them (calling *GC.start* didn't help)

([strace of the process](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=qLjqthkc))

Comment: My guess is it is not ruby doing this, but the web server writing a temp file for faster retrieval.  Does it do it if you open the file directly (ie: without calling the url)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby isn't to blame - it was apache writing access and error logs.